# API Request Resets State React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, state

I am working on a React Native project created with Expo. I have created two callbacks that get specific data from the Expo Location API and sets the data into the state. Each callback is in an interval that is defined in the useEffect() hook of the app, and they both run at separate time intervals. One runs 2 times every second, whereas the other one runs 4 times a minute. If I just run the program with the first callback in the useEffect hook, it runs perfectly fine, but when I run both intervals in the useEffect hook, the second one for some reason temporarily resets the state before the first callback runs and resupplies the accurate data. If I console.log(state.speed) at the top of the second callback function, it is 0, which should not be correct because the first callback gives it the right speed. If anyone can figure out how to properly implement two callback functions running at separate intervals in the useEffect hook without the state being reset, then that will be great. Thanks!

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar"; import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, SafeAreaView } from "react-native"; import { DateTime } from "luxon"; import { API_KEY, BASE_WEATHER_URL } from "../env"; import axios from "axios"; import * as Location from "expo-location";

const HUD = () => {   const [state, setState] = useState({
    speed: 0,
    direction: "N/A",
    speedUnits: "MPH",
    heading: 0,
    longitude: 0,
    latitude: 0,
    temperature: 0,
    city: "",
    region: "",   });


  const getGeolocation = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({
        accuracy: Location.Accuracy.Highest,
      });
      const { speed, heading, longitude, latitude } = location.coords;
      setState({
        ...state,
        speed: Math.round(speed * 2.2369363),
        direction: letterHeading(heading),
        heading: Math.round(heading),
        longitude,
        latitude,
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }   }, []);

  const getArea = useCallback(async () => {
    console.log(state.speed);
    let area = await Location.reverseGeocodeAsync({
      latitude: state.latitude,
      longitude: state.longitude,
    });
    setState({ ...state, city: area[0].city, region: area[0].region });   }, []);

  useEffect(async () => {
    // Orientation.lockToLandscapeRight();
    let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
    if (status !== "granted") {
      console.error("Permission to access location denied");
    }
    const locationInterval = setInterval(() => {
      getGeolocation();
    }, 500);
    const areaInterval = setInterval(() => {
      getArea();
    }, 5000);
    //The areaInterval, or getArea(), is the one that is resetting the state.speed
    return () => {
      clearInterval(locationInterval);
      clearInterval(areaInterval);
    };
  }, [getGeolocation, getArea]);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.block}>
        {/* <i class="fas fa-arrow-left" style={styles.backArrow} /> */}
        <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
          {/* <Text style={[styles.locationText, styles.mirrored]}>
            {state.city}, {state.region}
          </Text> */}
          <Text style={[styles.temperature, styles.mirrored]}>
            {state.temperature}° F
          </Text>
          <Text style={[styles.direction, styles.mirrored]}>
            {letterHeading(state.heading)}
          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
      <View style={[styles.block, { flexDirection: "row" }]}>
        <Text style={[styles.timeText, styles.mirrored]}>{displayTime()}</Text>
        <Text style={[styles.speedUnitText, styles.mirrored]}>
          {state.speedUnits}
        </Text>
        <Text style={[styles.speedometer, styles.mirrored]}>{state.speed}</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.block}>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
          <Image
            style={[styles.model, styles.mirrored]}
            source={require("../assets/NIssan_Murano_Overhead_Photo.png")}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
      <StatusBar style="black" />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

Please note that some irrelevant parts of the above program have been removed so that way you can focus on the issue, which is the getArea() callback, since every time it runs my program display state.speed as 0 for some reason

Comment: You need to include your dependencies in the `useCallback` calls -- the second argument is an array of dependencies. Right now, you're passing empty arrays.

Comment: @jnpdx What exactly would the dependencies be in this case? I'm just calling the API so I'm not sure what would be a dependency for each of the two callbacks. Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: Anything that you're using inside that closure that may change. `state`, in this case, for example -- that's why you're getting stale values.

Comment: @jnpdx That seems to have fixed the issue of the state being reset, so that's great! However one thing I am noticing is that the callback is being called many many more times than it is supposed to. Do you think that is because I am adding a state as a dependency, and two callbacks are manipulating the state at different times? Or do you think the dependency is irrelevant to this issue?

Comment: Too hard to tell without a [mre].

Comment: @RaamizAbbasi, is this 2 times a seconds and 4 times a minute something that have to be precise?

Comment: @Andrew It doesn't necessarily have to be precise but I would like it so that the getGeolocation() callback runs at least more than one time a second, and the getArea() callback a few times a minute. The reason why is because I am creating an app that involves updating the speed of a vehicle, which is why I need the getGeolocation() to run very quickly, whereas the getArea() is not that important The issue I am facing right now after I make the changes suggested by jnpdx is that the callbacks are running way too many times over and over and it is crashing the app